# How to Access Sharepoint 2007/2010/2013 _layouts folder

Tags: sharepoint, layout, insert

I'm trying to insert some data in the location
mysiteurl/_layouts/

'cause I had to use a third part software which uses data stored in that folder... I'm admin of the machine (Sharepoint 2010 on Windows server 2008R2) but the Sharepoint said I cannot access directly to that folder...

Is there any trick to insert data in that specific folder?

Comment: Give us some sort of clue about why and why you're doing that. For example are you developing your own WSP using visual studio?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate some layouts (masterpage, css, imgs) in an existing site collection.. For the master page there was no problem... But to upload the rest of files in the specific folder i cannot understand how to do that... When i try to access to localhost/_layouts/ SP told me i cannot view that page..

Comment: You can answer your own question. That way this question will be shown as having an answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're using SP 2007 the folder path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\
```

Sharepoint 2010 layouts folder path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\
```

If you're using SP 2013 the folder path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\
```

If you're using SP 2016 the folder path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\
```

Answer (score 6):

1. open **IIS** in SharePoint Web Front End
2. open sharepoint site and under that look for **_layouts** folder
   (Virtual Directory)
3. click **Explore** and actual server location will be opened

something like below address will be opend in sharepoint 2013 (office 15)

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE
```

[image]

Extra useful info:
you can easily put any assets  files including your js, css and Images here , it is much better that loading it to SharePoint which cause WSS **database** hit every time they are needed

[MSDN _Layouts Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb815343%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The _layouts virtual directory is available as a subfolder of every SharePoint Web site, which makes it easy and convenient to refer to _layouts files such as images or ECMAScript files (JScript, JavaScript) by using relative paths.
Support Details
Pages stored in the _layouts folder are available globally on the server